# weird "*** stack smashing detected ***" issue

Tags: 32bit-64bit, centos6

I have a simple batch program that works on 2 CentOS 6.6 machines ( a 32 bit machine and a 64 bit machine ), but not on a third CentOS 6.6 machine ( a 64 bit machine ).  So how can the exact same executable work on 2 machines, but not work on the third machine?

Note that I am not asking how to fix this issue, I am asking how the same exact executable can behave differently on 3 different machines.  I actually have 3 or four different C programs that match this behavior, but I am choosing the simplest one to troubleshoot the issue.  My theory is that something is setup differently at the OS level between the 3 machines ( maybe I forgot to install some library or set some environmental variable ).  I just need help narrowing down where to look, what OS type things to look at.

This probably should go onto serverfault, as it is more a server related question, but I was afraid people there would see my reference to C programs and ask me to come here, so I am going to start here.

Note that valgrind does not help.  I would just fix the issue in my code if that were the case, but it revealed no memory issues.  When I say it is simple, I mean it.  It just reads some records from the database, massages them, and then prints them to the screen.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was sort of an OS related issue, peripherally.  Basically, when I was installed my needed shared libraries, I installed the wrong version of my ODBC library ( a newer version then my code is used to and was compiled against ).  Once I got the older version installed correctly, the error went away.  So for anyone else having this problem with the same executable on one machine but not other machines, check your shared libraries, making sure the versions match.  Your executable may not like newer or older versions of a given library, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the stack smashing warnings / errors are caused by buffer overflow type issues.

I don't know enough about CentOS / Linux to know the exact way this gets configured (my main experience with this type of issue is when running on OpenBSD). Usually this stack smashing detection feature is enabled at compile time.

GDB may be able to help here if you compile your program with the debugging symbols enabled (-g) and load up the resulting core file to look at the backtrace.

For instance, in a simple test program on OpenBSD I see the following backtrace in GDB:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00001e13837081ea in kill () at <stdin>:2
#1  0x00001e1383745b2c in __stack_smash_handler (func=0x1e117f400ebf "test_smash", damaged=Variable "damaged" is not available.
) at /usr/src/lib/libc/sys/stack_protector.c:61
#2  0x00001e117f300e91 in test_smash () at test.c:10
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

where test_smash() is a function that intentionally overflows the stack.

Using this method should allow you to quickly determine which function is causing the stack overflow, and allow you to fix it in the source code.

Comment: Yes, I have seen very similar answers all over Google.  My question is why the same program works perfectly on one machine but not on the other, when the OS versions are so similar.  There is some OS level difference.  That is the problem.  I just don't know how to find it.

Comment: I was mainly responding to the last part "I would just fix the issue in my code if that were the case, but it revealed no memory issues." Using this method can help find the problem to allow you to fix it.